# Image is not a subtype of type imageprovider dynamic

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, runtime-error

When I select an image from the image selector, I am getting this error type file is not a subtype of the 'dynamic image provider' type
I've tried everything, but I can't make it work ... help me I don't know what else to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Image.file()` constructor.

```
return Image.file(
// _image has to be a File object. The one that you get when you use ImagePicker
_image
);
```